# change all <li> items background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background of all list items. I have this but it doesn't work.

```
// Get all <li> elements in the document
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li"); 

for (let i = 0; < x.length; i++;) {

x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
}
```

Comment: you dont need to do a loop just assign a css to the li example `$('li').addClass('red')` where class red has style background red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Jquery, the following line will do the trick.
$("li").css("background-color","red");

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

### Typo Error:

Replace `for (let i = 0; < x.length; i++;)` with `for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++)`

**Yet another typo:**
`;` after `i++`

> Your JS is correct, it's just having a typo.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
li {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>YOUR</li>
  <li>JAVASCRIPT</li>
  <li>IS</li>
  <li>WORKING</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also need to remove the `;` in `i++`.

Comment: just close as typo

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

// Var or Let works in the for loop

for(let list in lists) {
    lists[list].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Not jQuery but basic JavaScript

Comment: just close as typo

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo error, here the correct one:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li"); 

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
}
```

Another solution:

```
x.forEach((li) => li.style.backgroundColor = "red");
```

Comment: just close as typo

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a little `css` and `Javascript`.

**CSS:**

```
.red{
    background-color:red
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('li').addClass('red')
```

The `jquery` then adds a class of `red` to all `li` elements. In the included example I changed the selector so that it only changes the styling of the desired list. In case there are multiple lists on the page.

```js
$('ol.selected li').addClass('red')
```

```css
.red{
        background-color:red
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>List item one</li>
  <li>List item two</li>
  <li>List item three</li>
</ol>

<ol class='selected'>
  <li>List item one</li>
  <li>List item two</li>
  <li>List item three</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Array.
  from(document.getElementsByTagName("li"))
  .map(e => e.style.backgroundColor = "black");
```

or use

```
[]
  .slice
  .call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"))
  .map(e => e.style.backgroundColor = "black");
```

You might consider to use `forEach`, instead of `map` according to your taste.

P.S. There are plenty of resources explaining execution time and other acpects between two of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the code using a forEach loop to make it way easier.

```
let x = document.querySelector("li");
x.forEach(function(listElement){
this.style.background = "red";
]);
```

Thats the easiest non-jquery way of doing this. Picture it like this, a for each loop, is basically saying this: "Ok, so for each list element, I want the background to be red".

Hope that helped,
- Sami